# Google Analytics - Tracker Object from Activity

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am creating the Google Analytics Tracker object from an Activity. The issue is that I am getting an error in the cast operation done on this.getApplication(). Please let me know how to create a tracker object from an Activity.

```
public void sengToGoogleAnalytics() {
    Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) this.getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName(getString(R.string.memoryhome));
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}
```

Log

```
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free/kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.MemoryHome}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free/kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.MemoryHome}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): 
06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917):
```

Comment: are you using Google Analytics SDK?

Comment: Using Google Play Services

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Cause:**
The object returned by getApplication is `android.app.Application`, which throws a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), as indicated by the following line in the logcat

> 06-11 11:49:59.510: E/AndroidRuntime(2917): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to kids.animals.fruits.objects.brain.puzzle.memory.game.free.AnalyticsSampleApp06-11

**Solution:**
This can be caused if your manifest doesn't contain the [application element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm)

```
<application android:name=".YourApplication"...
</application>
```

Comment: contact me if your ever interested in a nomination. https://developers.google.com/experts/

Comment: sure @Dalm, will let u know :)