# android manifest application elements

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to use google analytic in my android application and I face a problem and it solved by other question in stackoverflow

[Goolge Analytics - Tracker Object from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155928/goolge-analytics-tracker-object-from-activity)

This problem was solved by using manifest element which is calling class activity in android:name

```
<application android:name=".googleanalytic"...
</application>
```

Now I want also to call another class which is valley appcontroller in android:name 
as follow the tutorial in this website
[Android JSON parsing using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

```
<application android:name=".volleyjson.app.AppController"...
</application>
```

My Question is how to call both class in manifest

```
 <application android:name=".volleyjson.app.AppController" + ".googleanalytic"
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify only one value in `android:name` i think you have to do something like this initializing Google Analytics

[Multiple application android:name tags in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499424/multiple-application-androidname-tags-in-manifest)